# Magento 2 How to stop spam / fake customers

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.3, spam

I have a lot of spam customers registered even I have already enabled **Captcha** validation on *Customer creation form*, but I wonder why there are still many fake / junk customers registered  everyday. Does this mean that some bot can actually figure out passing through the Captcha validation? and how do we prevent this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to change Magento's native captcha with Google reCaptcha.

Comment: Are you using SSL for your website?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I'm using SSL. I have just enabled Goolge reCaptcha, and disabled Magentos native captcha, and see how it goes. I'll give you update tomorrow. thanks for far :)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I haven't got any spam customers today. I think it helps with change Magentos native captcha to Google reCaptcha. thanks

Comment: Great, can I post my answer. Can you please up-vote if it helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change **Magento's Native Captcha** with **Google ReCaptcha**. It is much secure and intelligent than Magento's native captcha.

Verify that you are using valid **SSL certificate** for the website.

Check and change the following something which is not easy to guess:

- Password of all admin users for Magento admin panel
- MySQL/MariaDB password, which you are using in app/etc/env.php
- FTP/SSH credentials

Verify, that there is no custom PHP file residing in the document root or pub folders. If there is any, then validate the code it has.

This is because, customers/admin users can be added directly from the database or using a custom PHP code also.

Comment: change Magento's Native Captcha with Google ReCaptcha solved my problem.

Comment: Setup Google ReCaptcha, but still getting spam registration. Can fix issue if change all passwords?